# VBA Excel: add sheet with template already in Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question:

I have a sheet `TEMPLATE` in my workbook. I want to add a number of similar sheet in that workbook, using `TEMPLATE` as a template.

How do I do this in VBA Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 5 additional `TEMPLATES` you need to copy it 5 times in the loop:

```
Dim i as byte
for i=1 to 5
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy after:=sheets("TEMPLATE")
Next i
```

Comment: Follow-up question: how can I control the name of the new sheet?

Comment: what do you expect to have as a name of a new sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that makes 13 copies:

```
Sub qwerty()
    For i = 1 To 13
        Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy before:=Sheets(1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

modify this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to register here in case anyone stumble on this answer as I did, you can also do it with a range if you don't want to copy the whole sheet, for example if your "Template" is just a range from another sheet

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A2:L65536").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, Sheets("Data")).Range("A1")
```

What is important here:

Destination requires a range

Sheet.add returns a worksheet object.

so instead of passing sheetX.range as the Destination argument we are passing CreateNewSheetFunction.Range

Might not be a good example of code redability, but still, it's an option