# Subroutine Procedure too large. Breaking it up

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to build a Excel report from Access. Its rather larger. 15 tabs and alot of lines of code to format the sheet the way my manger wants this.
Problem is its too big and needs to be broke into a couple of Subroutine.
But I can seem to make 2 separate subroutines that will add data to one single excel file.

here is some of my code, too much to paste it all.
This is creating the first sheet and adding another. Will let me add about 10 sheets the it craps out because its too big, 
I just keep adding to the same sheet and when its done it just pops up for the user.

```
Sub Southwest()


'Southwest

On Error GoTo SubError

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer    

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

          ' Southwest ***************************************************************************************************



    'Early Binding DATA FIRST
    Set xlApp = Excel.Application

    xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)


       With xlSheet
       .Name = "Southwest"
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 10


         End With


'RETRIEVE DATA
    'SQL statement
    SQL = "SELECT VP, AVP, [Master Project ID], [Master Project Nm], [Budget Entity], Actuals, SORTABS, Forecast, [% Spent], Explanation, Status, [High Range], [Low Range], " & _
    "(Actuals - Actuals) / Actuals AS Discount " & _
    "FROM ActualsvsForecast " & _
    "Where AVP = 'West' " & _
    "ORDER BY VP, AVP, [Status] DESC, [SORTABS] DESC, [Master Project ID] "

    'Execute query and populate recordset
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    'If no data, don't bother opening Excel, just quit


    'BUILD SPREADSHEET
    'Create an instance of Excel and start building a spreadsheet

     xlApp.Visible = False

    intSheets = xlBook.Worksheets.Count
    Set xlSheetLast = xlBook.Worksheets(intSheets)
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add(, xlSheetLast, 1, xlWorksheet)


    With xlSheet
        .Name = "West"
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 10

        'Set column widths
        .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 1
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 50
        .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 50
        .Columns("M").ColumnWidth = 8

    .Range("A3").Activate
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        'Format columns
        .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Columns("G").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("J").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("K").NumberFormat = "###0.0%;-###0.0%;-"



        'build column headings
        .Range("A2").Value = ""
        .Range("B2").Value = "VP"
        .Range("C2").Value = "AVP"
        .Range("D2").Value = "Master Project ID"
        .Range("E2").Value = "Master Project Name"
        .Range("F2").Value = "Budget Entity"
        .Range("G2").Value = "Actuals"
        .Range("H2").Value = "Forecast"
        .Range("I2").Value = "High Range"
        .Range("J2").Value = "Low Range"
        .Range("K2").Value = "% Spent"
        .Range("L2").Value = "Explanation"
        .Range("M2").Value = "Status"


        'Format Column Headings
        .Range("B2:L2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("B2:L2").Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("B2:L2").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Range("B2:L2").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)


        'provide initial value to row counter
        i = 3
        'Loop through recordset and copy data from recordset to sheet
        Do While Not rs1.EOF

            .Range("B" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!VP, "")
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!AVP, "")
            .Range("D" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Master Project ID], "")
            .Range("E" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Master Project Nm], "")
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Budget Entity], "")
            .Range("G" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Actuals, 0)
            .Range("H" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Forecast, 0)
            .Range("I" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![High Range], 0)
            .Range("J" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Low Range], 0)
            .Range("K" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![% Spent], 0)
            .Range("L" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Explanation, "")
            .Range("M" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Status, "")

        'Center % [% Spent]
        .Range("K" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        'Row Height
        .Rows(i).RowHeight = 25


            i = i + 1
            rs1.MoveNext

        Loop

        'Formulas for total line
        'Count items
        .Range("B" & i, "E" & i).Merge
        .Range("B" & i).Value = "Total"
        .Range("B" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        'Sum Totals
        .Range("G" & i).Formula = "=SUM(G3:G" & i - 1
        .Range("H" & i).Formula = "=SUM(H3:H" & i - 1
        .Range("I" & i).Formula = "=SUM(I3:I" & i - 1
        .Range("J" & i).Formula = "=SUM(J3:J" & i - 1

        .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Cells.Font.Bold = True



        'grid-lines:
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

        .Range("C3:A" & i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("B3:D" & i - 1).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("B3:D" & i - 1).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        .Range("C3:K" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
        .Range("B3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium

        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        .Range("B3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
            '.Range("L3" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium

        'Add conditional formatting - only 3 allowed
        'With .Range("J3:J" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, 0.05, 0.0499)
            '.Interior.Color = RGB(157, 255, 157)
        'End With
        'With .Range("F3:F" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, 0.05, 0.0999)
           ' .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 155, 55)         'orange
       ' End With
        'With .Range("D3:L" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellRow, xlEqual, M3 = "RED")
            '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 53, 53)        'red
        'End With


        'Grid-line:  under total line
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium

        'Total Row Format
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Cells.Font.Size = 12
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Rows(i).RowHeight = 25

        i = i + -1

        .Range("B3", "B" & i).Merge
          .Range("B3").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("B3").Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("C3", "C" & i).Merge
         .Range("C3").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("C3").Cells.Font.Bold = True




    End With


'Andrew ************************************************************************************************************

    'RETRIEVE DATA
    'SQL statement
    SQL = "SELECT VP, AVP, [Master Project ID], [Master Project Nm], [Budget Entity], Actuals, SORTABS, Forecast, [% Spent], Explanation, Status, [High Range], [Low Range], " & _
    "(Actuals - Actuals) / Actuals AS Discount " & _
    "FROM ActualsvsForecast " & _
    "Where AVP = 'Andrew' " & _
    "ORDER BY VP, AVP, [Status] DESC, [SORTABS] DESC, [Master Project ID] "

    'Execute query and populate recordset
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)


    'BUILD SPREADSHEET
    'Create an instance of Excel and start building a new sheet

    'Early Binding
    'Set xlApp = Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = False
    'Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    'Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

    intSheets = xlBook.Worksheets.Count
    Set xlSheetLast = xlBook.Worksheets(intSheets)
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add(, xlSheetLast, 1, xlWorksheet)



    With xlSheet
        .Name = "Andrew"
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 10

        'Set column widths
        .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 1
        .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 12
        .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 50
        .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 17
        .Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 50
        .Columns("M").ColumnWidth = 8

    .Range("A3").Activate
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        'Format columns
        .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Columns("G").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("J").NumberFormat = "$#,##0_);($#,##0);-"
        .Columns("K").NumberFormat = "###0.0%;-###0.0%;-"



        'build column headings
        .Range("A2").Value = ""
        .Range("B2").Value = "VP"
        .Range("C2").Value = "AVP"
        .Range("D2").Value = "Master Project ID"
        .Range("E2").Value = "Master Project Name"
        .Range("F2").Value = "Budget Entity"
        .Range("G2").Value = "Actuals"
        .Range("H2").Value = "Forecast"
        .Range("I2").Value = "High Range"
        .Range("J2").Value = "Low Range"
        .Range("K2").Value = "% Spent"
        .Range("L2").Value = "Explanation"
        .Range("M2").Value = "Status"


        'Format Column Headings
        .Range("B2:L2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("B2:L2").Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("B2:L2").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Range("B2:L2").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)


        'provide initial value to row counter
        i = 3
        'Loop through recordset and copy data from recordset to sheet
        Do While Not rs1.EOF

            .Range("B" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!VP, "")
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!AVP, "")
            .Range("D" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Master Project ID], "")
            .Range("E" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Master Project Nm], "")
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Budget Entity], "")
            .Range("G" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Actuals, 0)
            .Range("H" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Forecast, 0)
            .Range("I" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![High Range], 0)
            .Range("J" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Low Range], 0)
            .Range("K" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![% Spent], 0)
            .Range("L" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Explanation, "")
            .Range("M" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Status, "")

        'Center % [% Spent]
        .Range("K" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        'Row Height
        .Rows(i).RowHeight = 25


            i = i + 1
            rs1.MoveNext

        Loop

        'Formulas for total line
        'Count items
        .Range("B" & i, "E" & i).Merge
        .Range("B" & i).Value = "Total"
        .Range("B" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        'Sum Totals
        .Range("G" & i).Formula = "=SUM(G3:G" & i - 1
        .Range("H" & i).Formula = "=SUM(H3:H" & i - 1
        .Range("I" & i).Formula = "=SUM(I3:I" & i - 1
        .Range("J" & i).Formula = "=SUM(J3:J" & i - 1

        .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Cells.Font.Bold = True



        'grid-lines:
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

        .Range("C3:A" & i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("B3:D" & i - 1).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("B3:D" & i - 1).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        .Range("C3:K" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
        .Range("B3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium

        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        .Range("C3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        .Range("B3:L" & i + 0).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("C3" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
            '.Range("L3" & i + 0).Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium

        'Add conditional formatting - only 3 allowed
        'With .Range("J3:J" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, 0.05, 0.0499)
            '.Interior.Color = RGB(157, 255, 157)
        'End With
        'With .Range("F3:F" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, 0.05, 0.0999)
           ' .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 155, 55)         'orange
       ' End With
        'With .Range("D3:L" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellRow, xlEqual, M3 = "RED")
            '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 53, 53)        'red
        'End With


        'Grid-line:  under total line
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium

        'Total Row Format
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Cells.Font.Size = 12
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Rows(i).RowHeight = 25

        i = i + -1

        .Range("B3", "B" & i).Merge
          .Range("B3").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("B3").Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("C3", "C" & i).Merge
         .Range("C3").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("C3").Cells.Font.Bold = True




    End With



SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
    messagebox = "Exit SUB"
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    xlApp.Visible = True
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True


    Exit Sub

SubError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "= " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "An error occurred"
    GoTo SubExit
```

Comment: You haven't really got a complete question here.

Comment: Large code is hard to maintain, but I am very skeptical of your claim that your code "craps out *because* its too big". I suspect that code size is just one of your problems.

Comment: The error I get is Compile Error: Procedure too Large.

Comment: But it work, its a mess but I am learning.

Comment: SO my question is how can I add more data to the same excel file in a 2nd Subroutine

Comment: compiled procedure cannot exceed 64kb. You should break it up into different sub routines.

Comment: Well, in that case you have thousands of lines of code in a single sub (64 K seems to be what triggers that error). If it doesn't compile -- in what sense does it "work"? Surely there must be *some* repetition in the code. If you wrote the code, my guess is that it was with a fair amount of copy/pasting/editing. Pay attention to where you did that. It is a sign of a sub needing to be written.

Comment: I am making the same spreadsheet over and over again. guess there has to be a way to do several at once or loop it or something. I am going to play with it and see.

Comment: it works when i build 10 sheets, when I add more then that its too much.

Comment: I am not building what I can on one sheet and copying it. Saves alot of lines of code. But not I am trying to run the loop to add the data from SQL and the Do wile not gives me an error. That part of the code has not changed and it makes no since to me why its not working.

Comment: I get an COmpile Error Loop without Do. but I have a do.

Comment: [How do I create/use a custom or default sheet template](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win016.htm), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380889/vba-excel-add-sheet-with-template-already-in-workbook

Answer (score 2):

> SO my question is how can I add more data to the same excel file in a 2nd Subroutine

Pass your object variables (`xlBook` and/or `xlSheet`) as parameters to the subroutines.

Comment: My code was a mess, I have cleaned it up and I am now using a loop and Variant and it all works except that SQL code.

Comment: Can I call a Variant from and array in a SQL statement?

Comment: 'SQL statement
    SQL = "SELECT VP, AVP, [Master Project ID], [Master Project Nm], [Budget Entity], Actuals, SORTABS, Forecast, [% Spent], Explanation, Status, [High Range], [Low Range], " & _
    "(Actuals - Actuals) / Actuals AS Discount " & _
    "FROM ActualsvsForecast " & _
    "Where AVP = strAVP(intCounterAVP) " & _
    "ORDER BY VP, AVP, [Status] DESC, [SORTABS] DESC, [Master Project ID] "

Comment: strAVP(intCounterAVP) is my variant and it works everyplace else

Comment: Or can I filter the query before the SQL statement?